# Mint17.2 install py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, linux-mint

I tried downloading the .exe files (problem: can't find a version 2.7 of python on computer + can't add the directory)

I tried using the:

```
pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files
```

but brings this error:

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I then tried to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev

sudo easy_install green let
sudo easy_install gevent
```

with this error:

```
mock requires setuptools>=17.1. Aborting installation
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

Comment: Doesn't py2exe use some Windows module?

Comment: I believe it is supposed to work on linux as well

Comment: Well, I tried to use py2exe on Linux. But I got some error says need function that only work on Windows. However this error means that **setuptools** version is too low, try update it?